# Displaying user selected answers in android

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been working on an android test, all of which I have working mostly. When the user selects their answers they are re-directed to a results screen that tells them how many they got right and wrong. I want to add a new feature in my practice mode where its shows them what answer they choose and what the correct answer is. But I was just curious as to how I would call the variable

```
TextView tv;
Button btnNext;
RadioGroup rg;
RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3;
String question[] = {"This classes course number", "What is the name of the program we used to make apps", "Android is a Which kind of software?"};
String ans[] = {" 2250", "Android Studio", "Operating System"};
String opt[] = {"2230", "2240", "2250", "Dev Kit 2010", "Android Creation", "Android Studio", "Operating System", "Antivirus", "Application"};


int flag = 0;
public static int marks, correct, wrong;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_csits);


    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvque);
    btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
    rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
    rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
    rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);

    tv.setText(question[flag]);
    rb1.setText(opt[0]);
    rb2.setText(opt[1]);
    rb3.setText(opt[2]);


    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioButton your_answers = (RadioButton) findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            String ansText = your_answers.getText().toString();

            marks = correct - wrong;

            if (ansText.equalsIgnoreCase(ans[flag])) {
                correct++;
            } else {
                wrong++;
            }
            flag++;
            if (flag < question.length) {
                tv.setText(question[flag]);
                rb1.setText(opt[flag * 3]);
                rb2.setText(opt[(flag * 3) + 1]);
                rb3.setText(opt[(flag * 3) + 2]);
            } else {
                marks = correct - wrong;
                Intent intent = new Intent(CSITSActivity.this, ResultsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are trying to do because your question was not that clear but if you are trying to pass values from one intent to another you can put the chosen answers in an array and pass them to the new intent like this :

```
String[] chosenAnswers = {"a","a","b"}
Intent startIntent = new Intent(this,ResultsActivity.class);
startIntent.putExtra("chosen", chosenAnswers); //"chosen" is a random tag that can be anything but is used to get back the value of the list in the new intent
this.startActivity(startIntent);
```

Then from your ResultsActivity.class you could get the value of that array by using :

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String[] chosenAnswers = i.getStringArrayExtra("chosen");
```

this can also be done with an ArrayList using the same method except when getting the list in the new intent use :

```
i.getStringArrayListExtr(chosen);
```

not sure if that is what you are trying to achieve but hope it helps.